# PHPDocumenter No summary for class

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

I am using PHPDocuementer and I keep getting these messages for my classes:

```
Parsing /code/vendor/prodigyview/helium/app.class.php
  No summary for class \prodigyview\helium\He2App
```

But when code is the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * The main application for instantiaing the He2MVC Framework and bringing together the parts required for the system to work.
 * 
 * The application is what is called with Helium is first initiliaed in the frontend controller. It will autoload the components,
 * set the registry and then send the application into the router. The boostrap of the framework should be called sometime during
 * this point.
 * 
 * @package prodigyview\helium
 */
namespace prodigyview\helium;

class He2App extends \PVStaticInstance {

}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Summary for class should be placed right before class definition. What you have now is file summary.

Comment: @u_mulder I flipped the namespace an description, and it threw this error: Parsing /code/vendor/prodigyview/helium/app.class.php
  No summary was found for this file

Comment: Ahhh I think I see, file summary and class summary are different!

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one docblock you have should be moved down to just above the `class` line.  Its current location is being interpreted as the file-level docblock rather than a class-level docblock.

After doing this, you *might* start seeing warnings about file-level docblock missing.  Just add a new docblock at the same place you have the current example one.  You could use an exact copy of the one you already have up there, since its content seems to fit for the file as well as the class.